# How do I only display a specific child during which corresponds to today's date in Firebase using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, date

So I'm trying to figure out how I'm supposed to structure my data and how to iterate through it depending on the date that is received from the database.

Here is the structure right now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K037M.jpg

"Datum" contains the dates of each day (Epoch time) and as every date has a child which contain only a "Text" with the actual text as value. Eventually these epoch times would be at the very start of a day at 00:01AM f.e.

The app is supposed to work like this: If I open it on a certain date, I only want to show content from corresponding child where the dates match up. The content changes at midnight.

Here's my code so far:

```
    var query = firebase.database().ref("Datum").orderByKey();
    query.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
         snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            // childData will be the actual contents of the child
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            var text_val = childSnapshot.val().Text;

            $("#dagett").append(text_val);

            //test
            console.log("got the data!", childData);
         });
  });
```

Right now the code gets the content from both children and appends it into a string. Not really what I want though. I only want to display the correct child's content.

Now the problem I'm having is that I am not sure how to iterate through each child and only display which child has the "correct" date. I'm aware of startAt() and endAt() but the only solution I've found so far for those is to create js variables which contain also epoch time, but this doesn't really solve my problem, because I'm going to have a hundred dates with each of those containing text and/or an image. I don't want to define specific js variables with the exact time and then query using those functions. There has to be a better way.

Bonus: I'd also like to be able to include images for some dates, I'm not sure if I can just add another child to that specific date and then use it in some ways or to combine the query with Storage?

Please keep in mind that this is not a commercial app and there's only one other person that is going to use it. Therefore it doesn't need to perform fast or anything.

I hope this question is clear enough.

Comment: At which midnight? Zulu or local timezone?

Comment: At the local timezone for the person using the app. It's going to be different from the timezone where I will be coding it.

Answer (score 1):

> Eventually these epoch times would be at the very start of a day at 00:01AM f.e.

So if we calculate the todays timestamp at that time, it would match the one from the db exactly:

```
 const today = new Date();
 today.setMinutes(1);
 today.setHours(0);
 today.setSeconds(0);
 today.setMilliseconds(0);
 const ts = +today;
```

Now you can just get the text that is stored at that exact key. Something like:

```
 snapshot.child(ts).val().Text
```

Comment: What does the +today in the ts variable do? Specifically the + sign. Do you have any idea how to loop through every child in the database like I needed?

Comment: @samuel you dont want to loop. And the `+` converts it to a number.

Comment: But how do I make sure it switches at midnight? Do I keep the structure of the database as it is? Won't it display all dates content after whatever date I'm on as well? How does it know to only show one date's content?

Comment: @samuel cause at midnight the day changes

Comment: I'm having trouble still. What I'm trying: Add data to database, another branch with a timestamp that has not yet been crossed, change the today constant to a date which has not happened yet as well but is before the timestamp in the database. Then `
        var query = firebase.database().ref("Datum").orderByKey();
        query.once("value")
  .       then(function(snapshot) {

   try {
    var mytext = snapshot.child(ts).val().Text;
     $("#dagett").append(mytext);
 } catch(e) {
     if (e instanceof TypeError) {
      console.log("ERROR!");
     }
 }
 });'

Comment: Just adding the 'var mytext = snapshot.child(ts).val().Text;
   $("#dagett").text(mytext);' into the function returns "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property of 'null' "

Comment: Sorry for spam, but it seems like I can only do snapshot.val().Text; and not .child() like you suggested. That's when I get the error above. A problem in my structure maybe?

Comment: @samuel maybe because there is no message for today?

Comment: So I tried adding 3 messages and setting the time to 17.30, one for yesterday, one for today and one for tomorrow. It still returned the same error. I then removed the ' .Text ' and it resulted in giving me, i suppose an object (?) with all three children. Take a look at these photos: 1. the new database structure https://imgur.com/a/QWjCyL4  2. the object that was returned from .val(): https://imgur.com/a/2t7rtKj and 3. my code right now: 
https://imgur.com/a/823B8pI

Comment: Then I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. You're being a bit vague :D . Is the code to create const ts meant to be the date where the content switches? Then I don't see why I can't change it for testing purposes, as long as the milliseconds in the database for each date is exactly the same as ts. I changed the children to only have the milliseconds as key now and then the text as value, instead of them having ANOTHER child with a key "Text" and then the actual text as value. If you could explain a bit more I would be grateful.

Comment: No, I do not. Can we carry this conversation elsewhere? Do you have discord where we can chat?

Comment: I couldn't add you for some reason : samochips#1152 here's mine